# Eichler Shimura in higher genera

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, modular-forms, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

Let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the moduli stack of smooth elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$. There is a local system, $\mathcal{H}$, on $\mathcal{M}$ with fibre $H^{1}(E,\mathbb{C})$ at the $\mathbb{C}$-point of $\mathcal{M}$ corresponding to the curve $E$. This is simply the local system underlying the first variation of hodge structure corresponding  to the universal curve on $\mathcal{M}$.

The Eichler Shimura isomorphism computes the cohomology of the symmetric powers of this local system. Note that it is normally phrased as a statement about group cohomology of $\Gamma:=SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ with coefficients in its natural polynomial representations, these two statements are equivalent according to the analytic uniformization of $\mathcal{M}$ by $\mathfrak{h}$.

I'd like to know a higher genus version of this computation. That is, we replace $\mathcal{M}$ with $\mathcal{M}_{g}$. The definition of $\mathcal{H}$ is exactly as above. What is its cohomology? I've been unable to find anything of use.